# How to find the correct Matrices with INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, vba

I have 10 different matrices, each matrices represents a region.  For example: Canada, South West, Florida, etc. Within each matrix is a list of products in the rows and a list of products in the columns.  All of the matrices have been created as tables in excel with the names being their region names.  The values in the matrix represent the discount given to a customer if they purchase BOTH of those products in that region (The matrices are on a different tab from the lookup data).  For example, in the matrix below, if a customer in Canada purchases Doll and Energy Drink, they will be given a $10 Discount.

How would you go about creating an equation in column D of the example below that returns that dollar value based on all three of these criteria: correct matrix, correct product (row), correct product (column).  I do apologize for now posting an INDEX/MATCH equation to work from but I'm rather new to Excel and am not sure where to start.  I will reply promptly to any questions you may have, Thanks!

```
Canada Matrix Example  (Table Name = Canada)

           Energy Drink    Phone    Bag    
Doll         $10           $20      $15
Hat          $5            $13      $17
Stapler      $8            $14      $23


Data Sheet

Column A     Column B     Column C      Column D (Output)
Canada       Doll         Energy Drink    Equation (=$10)
Florida      Hat          Phone           Equation
South West   Stapler      Phone           Equation
Canada       Hat          Notepad         Equation (=$14)
```

Comment: Why not combine the ten different matrices into one single matrix, with an additional column that for the Region?  Then you could use an INDEX/MATCH formula that matches on the Region and whatever secondary criteria, to reference within the array.

Comment: Because I'm developing this model for the marketing department and they prefer to see the information and update the information as a Region based seperate matrices.  It's one of those things where its the way its always been done and thats how they want to look at it and make their updates

Comment: If you want to find the discount of any combination of product, you have to find the single discount for each one. It's possible to do that with matrices excel's formulas, however it seems to me that this is more like a math problem...

Comment: Interesting, I'm unfamiliar with these formulas

Comment: @oryan5000, if you're responding to my comment, well... To find the discount of each item, you have to solve a linear equations system. You can do that in excel with the `MINVERSE` formula to invert the coefficients equations matrix and solve the system by multiplying that with the independent coefficient array with the formula `MMULT`.

Comment: @oryan5000, I just mentioned the idea of finding the discount for each item because you putted both "Hat" and "Stapler" on the last row of your result. To find the combination of this two, a single INDEX/MATCH formula will not work.

Comment: Index Match will work to return rows and columns based on "Hat" and "Stapler" within their respective matrices.  I will look into your suggested mathematical approach tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants to see the answer I came up with.  It involves a series of INDEX/CHOOSE/VLOOKUP/MATCH functions.  The Regions are simply the names I gave the matrices

```
=INDEX(CHOOSE(VLOOKUP(B:B,xref!L:M,2,0),Canada[#All],Central[#All],Florida[#All],GreatLakes[#All],MidAtlantic[#All],NorthEast[#All],NorthWest[#All],SouthCentral[#All],SouthEast[#All],SouthWest[#All]),MATCH(F2,CHOOSE(VLOOKUP(B:B,xref!L:M,2,0),Canada[[#All],[MODEL]],Central[[#All],[MODEL]],Florida[[#All],[MODEL]],GreatLakes[[#All],[MODEL]],MidAtlantic[[#All],[MODEL]],NorthEast[[#All],[MODEL]],NorthWest[[#All],[MODEL]],SouthCentral[[#All],[MODEL]],SouthEast[[#All],[MODEL]],SouthWest[[#All],[MODEL]]),0),MATCH(E2,CHOOSE(VLOOKUP(B:B,xref!L:M,2,0),Canada[#Headers],Central[#Headers],Florida[#Headers],GreatLakes[#Headers],MidAtlantic[#Headers],NorthEast[#Headers],NorthWest[#Headers],SouthCentral[#Headers],SouthEast[#Headers],SouthWest[#Headers]),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following INDEX/MATCH formula that will work within the single Canada array provided in the sample.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($B9,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH($C9,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

You could then copy this into several layers of IF statements which point each copy of the INDEX/MATCH formula to the appropriate Region array in the worksheet.

As long as Column B is always the Row, and Column C is always the Column, then this should work fine.  In the case of the provided sample, the last transaction (Canada, Hat, Stapler, return 14) does not work because the reference array does not have a Stapler column.  I assume the working file has a more expansive array.

Comment: Heck yea, I think this is going to work.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

[image]

As long as your tables are named ranges it wouldn't matter where they're located.

I broke up the logic into a number of columns but you could just as easily combine them into a single formula.

The key is that:

```
INDEX(TableRangeHere, 1, 0)
INDEX(TableRangeHere, 0, 1)
```

return the entire first row and column respectively of the named range

Comment: Uhhhh, I can't view the image, likely due to a workplace firewall